# Java: How to convert com.google.api.services.drive.model.File to InputStream?

Tags: java, spring, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am new to google drive integration. 
I saved an image in google drive and I got that file by below method.

```
File file = getDriveService().files().get(fileId).execute();
```

Now when I tried to convert this file into InputStream and write this InputStream in HttpResponse then the file returns but the image is not displayed.

```
public InputStream convertGoolgeFileToInputStream( String fileId ) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        getDriveService().files().get(fileId).executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        return in;

        //return getDriveService().files().get(fileId).executeAsInputStream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try checking the download example [Drive sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java)

```
private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
      throws IOException {
    // create parent directory (if necessary)
    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle()));

    MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
        new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
    downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
    downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getDownloadUrl()), out);
  }
```